# Fixing WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

On Wordpress 4.9.5, I am getting this error on the admin panel when I enable the Simple Error Log plugin.

Here is the error that we get:

> WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for
>   query INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`,
>   `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_content_filtered`,
>   `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `post_type`,
>   `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`,
>   `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,
>   `post_parent`, `menu_order`, `post_mime_type`, `guid`) VALUES (14,
>   '2018-04-17 18:24:27', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '', 'Auto Draft',
>   '', 'auto-draft', 'post', 'open', 'open', '', '', '', '', '2018-04-17
>   18:24:27', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, 0, '', '') made by wp_dashboard,
>   do_meta_boxes, call_user_func, wp_dashboard_quick_press,
>   get_default_post_to_edit, wp_insert_post

I have tried repair this table from PHPMYADMIN, also tried this https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/09/12/mysql-fix-error-wordpress-database-error-duplicate-entry-key-primary-query-insert-wp_options/ and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165277/new-posts-defaulting-to-0-primary-key but it doesn't resolve.

Pls advise what could be wrong and how to fix that.

Comment: Please show the table schema for that table.

Comment: think, the problem is with disabled auto increment for wp_posts table

Comment: i encounter this problem, the primary key column has a value of 0 then when you use the auto increment that error will occur, try to truncate first then, try to insert new 1

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and the following error message was displaying on top of one of my websites:

WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY']
INSERT INTO `Umr_actionscheduler_actions` (`hook`, `status`, `scheduled_date_gmt`, `scheduled_date_local`, `schedule`, `group_id`, `args`) VALUES ('wpforms_email_summaries_fetch_info_blocks', 'pending', '2023-07-02 18:51:31', '2023-07-02 18:51:31', 'O:32:"ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule":5:{s:22:"\0*\0scheduled_timestamp";i:1688323891;s:18:"\0*\0first_timestamp";i:1688323891;s:13:"\0*\0recurrence";i:604800;s:49:"\0ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule\0start_timestamp";i:1688323891;s:53:"\0ActionScheduler_IntervalSchedule\0interval_in_seconds";i:604800;}', '2', '{"tasks_meta_id":null}')
Skip to main content

This article helped me to solve the issue - https://www.newzealandgoonline.co.nz/how-to-fix-wordpress-database-error-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-primary-for-query-insert-into-wp_usermeta/

**In short - set auto-increment to the Primary key of the table.**

According to the error message I opened the table "Umr_actionscheduler_actions" in phpMyAdmin. After that clicked on Structure and then clicked on Change next to the primary key - in my case "action_id"

Pressed the check mark under AI and clicked on Save. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

... maybe you have to change the id of an existent entry before changing the column settings. If so, you will get an alert "will cause double entry". Look after an ID = 0 and change it to the highest ID value + 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).